# Getting Windows Phone and HttpClient PCL working

Tags: windows-phone-7, dotnet-httpclient, printer-control-language

I'm trying to use the new HttpClient PCL in a Windows Phone 7.1 project. The project is using Microsoft.Net.Http 2.1.3-beta from NuGet.

Code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.geonames.org/");
var resp = client.GetAsync("earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=bertt").Result;
var earthquakesJson = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This code works fine in a Windows Forms application.

When debugging the application just stops working on method HttpClient.GetAsync (on emulator or device). Internet is working on device/emulator.

Steps to reproduce:

. create Windows Phone 7.1 app (file -> new -> project)

. nuget command: 'install-package microsoft.net.http -pre'

. add code above to MainPage

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your problem do the following:

Install the Microsoft Async for WP7.1: `install-package microsoft.Bcl.Async`

Change your code to:

```cs
private async void GetData() {
   var client = new HttpClient();

   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.geonames.org/");
   var earthquakesJson = await client.GetStringAsync("earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=bertt");
   ...      
}
```